# how to develop a button menu in the main activities with kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to build an app where users have have the option of selecting from a list of calculation buttons in the main activity. The selection of each button would direct the user to the respective activity. Please see my code attempt using kotlin. My app crashes whenever I select an option. How could this issue be solved? [image]

```
    package com.example.myapplication
    
    import android.content.Intent
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.widget.Button
    
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var btnprobate: Button? = null
    private var btnconveyance: Button? = null
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    
    val btnprobate : Button = findViewById(R.id.btn_probate)
    val btnconveyance: Button = findViewById(R.id.btn_conveyance)
    
    btnprobate.setOnClickListener{
    val probateintent = Intent(this, ProbateActvity::class.java)
    startActivity(probateintent)
    }
    btnconveyance.setOnClickListener{
    val conveyanceintent = Intent(this, ConveyanceActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(conveyanceintent)
    
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: If your app is crashing, look in the logcat tab to find the error message and stack trace and include it in the question.

Comment: You have declared buttons with the same name one in the OnCreate and another on top. I am assuming because of the null value to the button which is globally declared your app is crashing. You can try to remove it from the global declaration. Or you can paste the crash to understand more.

Answer (score 0):

`private var btnprobate: Button? = null`

`private var btnconveyance: Button? = null`

you need to delete those 2 lines under `class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()`
since you already declare it inside `onCreate` method.

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding the `btnprobate` and `btnconveyance` global declarations.
Change your code like this:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var btnprobate: Button? = null
    private var btnconveyance: Button? = null
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        
        btnprobate = findViewById(R.id.btn_probate)
        btnconveyance = findViewById(R.id.btn_conveyance)
        
        btnprobate?.setOnClickListener{
            val probateintent = Intent(this, ProbateActvity::class.java)
            startActivity(probateintent)
        }
        btnconveyance?.setOnClickListener{
            val conveyanceintent = Intent(this, ConveyanceActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(conveyanceintent)
        }
    }
}
```

Anyway, You can improve your implementation by using [view binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding):

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        
        binding.btnProbate.setOnClickListener{
            val probateintent = Intent(this, ProbateActvity::class.java)
            startActivity(probateintent)
        }
        binding.btnConveyance.setOnClickListener{
            val conveyanceintent = Intent(this, ConveyanceActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(conveyanceintent)
        }
    }
}
```